# Are C++ implementations allowed to assume any rvalue reference function parameter is unique?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

From § 17.6.4.9 of ISO/IEC 14882:2011(E) (C++11):

> Each of the following applies to all arguments to functions deﬁned in
>   the C++ standard library, unless explicitly stated otherwise.
>   [snip]
>   — If a function argument binds to an rvalue reference parameter, the
>   implementation may assume that this parameter is a unique reference to
>   this argument.

This specification only applies to standard library functions, but it seems like the whole point of rvalue references is for this kind of assumption to be possible. If I have a function that takes an rvalue reference and pass it one (either through a temporary or `std::move`), can the implementation legally perform optimizations that assume it's unique? If not, do any implementations do so anyway?

Comment: I'm not sure your question. It seems the answer is right in the quote you have: `the implementation may assume that this parameter is a unique`

Comment: The quote answers it for standard library functions. But what about functions defined in the program itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The language does not itself mandate that an rvalue reference cannot alias any other object, this is simply a stated pre-condition of standard library functions.  So if by "implementation" you mean the compiler, then no - the compiler will not perform any optimizations based on this requirement, certainly not in code that you write.

If a particular compiler has some kind of extensions that allow code to convey aliasing information, then that pre-condition makes it is possible for standard library functions to take advantage of such extensions. That kind of aliasing information may make it possible for the compiler to perform some optimizations.

In any case, the main consequence of the statement is that the standard library implementation does not need to behave reasonably in the face of unreasonable aliasing of function parameters. For example, if you construct a pair with

```
std::vector<int> some_vector(100, 42);
auto p = std::make_pair(std::move(some_vector), some_vector);
```

there's no guarantee that `p.first == p.second`.

The absence of a requirement like this for lvalue reference parameters means that the standard library has to do some crazy things to make sure that code like `vector.insert(vector.end(), vector[3])` works even if the vector has to be reallocated. I imagine the committee thought it was unrealistic for implementations to detect rvalue aliasing and have to maybe-move-only-sometimes.

Comment: Oooh, I see. The "implementation" in the quote referred to the implementation _of the function_, not the implementation of the language.

Comment: @DyP I suppose `std::make_pair()` is a good example of a non-constructor, non-assignment operator function in the standard library that has more than one argument that can be a reference, at least one of which can be an rvalue reference. `std::make_pair(std::move(some_container), some_container)` for example would have unspecified results.

Comment: @DyP Assignment is NOT an example, since it can't have multiple arguments - let alone multiple arguments that alias. I'm an idiot, thanks for the reminder. Better now?

Comment: @Casey Nah, your `make_pair` example is good. I think `vector.insert` isn't as hard though, you just have to take care of the order (allocate new storage, copy new elements, move old elements).

Comment: +1.  Not unrealistic to implement, after all, the standard requires it for `vector::insert(const_iterator, lvalue)`.  It is just that the whole point of moving things is optimization.  So it seems unreasonable to ask the client to suffer the expense of having `vector::insert` do the alias check.  And if the client really needs to do something like that, it is very easy to create an actual temporary to move into:  `v.insert(i, T(move(v[3])));`.  I.e. the alias check is a feature you only pay for if you use.  You pay for it by creating an explicit temporary if you need it.